# R -- Shift Multiple Rows in a Data Frame Without a Loop

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was any way to perform this shift of rows without a loop in R?  I have data from a machine that performs sequential jobs of varied length. I want to shift the data so that there is no work being done on the weekend days

Data prior to shift

```
        Date  Job
1   2019-12-1 Job1
2   2019-12-2 Job1
3   2019-12-3 Job2
4   2019-12-4 Job2
5   2019-12-5 Job2
6   2019-12-6 Job3
7   2019-12-7 Job3
8   2019-12-8   NA
9   2019-12-9   NA
10 2019-12-10   NA
```

Data After Shift

```
         Date  Job Day_Of_Week
1  2019-12-01   NA      Sunday
2  2019-12-02 Job1      Monday
3  2019-12-03 Job1     Tuesday
4  2019-12-04 Job2   Wednesday
5  2019-12-05 Job2    Thursday
6  2019-12-06 Job2      Friday
7  2019-12-07   NA    Saturday
8  2019-12-08   NA      Sunday
9  2019-12-09 Job3      Monday
10 2019-12-10 Job3     Tuesday
```

Script:

```
data=data.frame(
                     Date=c("2019-12-1","2019-12-2","2019-12-3","2019-12-4","2019-12-5","2019-12-6","2019-12-7","2019-12-8","2019-12-9","2019-12-10"), 
                     Job=c("Job1","Job1","Job2","Job2","Job2","Job3","Job3",NA,NA,NA)
                     )


  data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%y-%m-%d") 
  data$Day_Of_Week<- weekdays(as.Date(data$Date))
  data$Job<-as.character(data$Job)

  lower_data<-NA
  upper_data<-NA


  for ( row in 1:nrow(data)){


    if(data[row,"Day_Of_Week"] %in% c('Saturday','Sunday')){
      if(row>1){
        upper_data <- data[1:row-1,]
        lower_data <- data[row:nrow(data),]
        lower_data <- transform(lower_data, Job = c(NA, Job[-nrow(lower_data)]))
        lower_data$Date<- as.Date(lower_data$Date, "%y-%m-%d" )
        data<-rbind(upper_data,lower_data)
      }else{
        data <- transform(data, Job = c(NA, Job[-nrow(data)]))
        data$Date<- as.Date(data$Date, "%y-%m-%d" )

      }


      } 

  }

  View(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some steps could be simplified but here is one way with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  mutate(Date = as.Date(Date), 
         Day_Of_Week = weekdays(Date), 
         is_weekend = cumsum(Day_Of_Week %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday')),
         New_index = row_number() - is_weekend,
         New_index = replace(New_index, New_index == 0 | 
                             Day_Of_Week %in% c('Saturday', 'Sunday'), NA),
         New_Job = Job[New_index]) %>%
  select(-is_weekend, New_index)

#         Date  Job Day_Of_Week New_index New_Job
#1  2019-12-01 Job1      Sunday        NA    <NA>
#2  2019-12-02 Job1      Monday         1    Job1
#3  2019-12-03 Job2     Tuesday         2    Job1
#4  2019-12-04 Job2   Wednesday         3    Job2
#5  2019-12-05 Job2    Thursday         4    Job2
#6  2019-12-06 Job3      Friday         5    Job2
#7  2019-12-07 Job3    Saturday        NA    <NA>
#8  2019-12-08 <NA>      Sunday        NA    <NA>
#9  2019-12-09 <NA>      Monday         6    Job3
#10 2019-12-10 <NA>     Tuesday         7    Job3
```